# Remapping CAPS_LOCK on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: suspend, remapping, capslock

I would like to do the following with my <kbd>CAPS_LOCK</kbd> key:

1. Remap <kbd>CAPS_LOCK</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to the left arrow key
2. Remap <kbd>CAPS_LOCK</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to the down arrow key, etc
3. Allow <kbd>CAPS_LOCK</kbd> to STAY as a <kbd>CAPS_LOCK</kbd> key if it's just pressed on its own
4. Allow this mapping to survive after my laptop wakes up from suspend/hibernate.

I've been looking around everywhere and I'm very confused. Some sites say you shouldn't use `xmodmap` since it's old. Some sites say you should twiddle with some file in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, whereas others call for `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
I would appreciate any help.